# Drush: Listing all modules installed on multiple servers

Tags: 6, drush

I have many servers installed on the same network, and I want to check them all to see if they need updates.  This requires me to login to each server and run `drush up` and check the results.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this, maybe a script or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can add [Drush Aliases](http://drupal.org/node/670460) for each site, and then add an alias containing all your sites.

Then:

$ drush @allsites up

Answer (score 1):

First step: upgrade to drush-5.x-dev.  Next, make one alias file per site called SITENAME.aliases.drushrc.inc, placing each in a valid location for aliases.  Inside each of these, define your alias for your live site in a consistent way:

```
$aliases['live'] = array(
  'uri' => ...
  'root' => ...
);
```

In drush-5.x-dev, any operation on the special group alias `@live` will execute on all aliases named "live", so you can just do this:

drush @live --no pm-updatecode

That will give you a nice report tagged with the name of each of your live sites.  On Drush 4 (or Drush 5), you can also explicitly define an alias list:

```
$aliases['all-live'] = array(
  'site-list' => '@site1.live', '@site2.live'
);
```

The usage of this alias would then be the same as before:

drush @all-live --no pm-updatecode

In order for this to work seamlessly, you will also need to set up ssh keys on your remote systems so that Drush can connect without a password.  There's a lot of good documentation on how to do this, such as http://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh.  Also, the drush-extras project has a Drush command that will help push public keys to remote servers.

Comment: Also try the new status-report command in drush-5, which will give you a quick way to view the status report page of your remote sites.